# faster way to compute `LU(A*A')`

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

A fairly common operation in applied math is to compute the LU decompositiion of a matrix times it's transpose/adjoint. This can be problematic numerically since roundoff errors in `A*A'` can cause the matrix to not be positive (semi) definite. Also, computing this the obvious way involves 2 (technically not quite) cubic operations. Is there any way of computing this without first computing `A*A'` (iterative methods are OK).

Comment: Did you already consider computing a QR decomposition of $A^T$, so that $AA^T=R^TR$? For LU you would then only need to shift the diagonals from $L=R^TD^{-1}$ to $U=DR$.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a widely known method? I looked around a bit, but haven't seen it before.

Comment: Yes, that is a standard trick, for instance in the computation of a pseudo-inverse (with known rank, rank-detection itself is better with the SVD).